# How to do environment setup for jhipster for java development

Tags: jhipster

I am new to JHipster.I have gone through all the steps for JHipster SetUp in Windows.

**First Issue :**

**Unable to create Jhipster Project**

I have followed the below steps.

1.Install Java from the Oracle website.

2.Install Maven (recommended). If you prefer to use Gradle instead, don't install it, as JHipster ships with the Gradle Wrapper.

3.Install Git from git-scm.com. We recommend you also use a tool like SourceTree if you are starting with Git.

4.Install Node.js from the Node.js website. This will also install npm, which is the node package manager we are using in the next commands.

5.Install Yeoman: npm install -g yo

6.Install Bower: npm install -g bower

7.Depending on your preferences, install either Grunt (recommended) with npm   install -g grunt-cli or Gulp.js with npm install -g gulp.

8.Install JHipster: npm install -g generator-jhipster.

But i am getting errors while creating JHipster project using command prompt.

**Second Issue :**

**How we can import the existing project from JHipster git to eclipse**

I downnloaded a sample JHipster project fro git and while trying to import the same project in to workspace i am facing an error like:

jdt apt pluging is not getting in eclipse to build that project....

Comment: What errors? Please provide logs.

Comment: For eclipse, did you follow https://jhipster.github.io/configuring_ide_eclipse.html

Comment: **Hi  @Gaël Marziou ** Thanks for your reply.I have tried the steps to importing a maven project.while importing it is asking for **"jdt apt"** plugins and unable to install the mentioned plugin in eclipse.I am using Juno.

Comment: Nobody in the JHipster dev team uses Eclipse but some of our users do, search in the closed issues you may find some solutions. https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Rather than Juno, I would suggest using Spring Tool Suite - http://spring.io/tools/sts

It's an Eclipse distribution that bundles a comprehensive set of plugins enabling one to work with Spring projects.

I found Eclipse to be weak when working with Javascript and HTML.  I switched to Intellij almost a year ago and am very happy with the decision.